# Declaration of overload operator- of objects with 2 different types

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a template-class and wrote a operator- which should do the math with 2 objects of different type and return it as a new object. Now i'm wondering how can i declare this operator- in my class, since something like

```
template<typename S> 
friend auto operator-(const XY<T>,const XY<S>)->XY<decltype(T-S)>;
```

isn't allowed?
Here is my example code:

```
template <typename T>
class XY{
private:
    T x

...

// template<typename S> 
// friend auto operator-(const XY<T>, const XY<S>)->XY<decltype(T-S)>;

};

template <typename T, typename S>
auto operator-(const XY<T> z1, const XY<S> z2)->XY<decltype(z1.x - z2.x)>{
    decltype(z1.x - z2.x) x;
    x = (z1.x - z2.x);
    XY<decltype(x)> n(x);

    return n;
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `->Complex<...>` and `->XY<...>`? Unless this is a new syntax feature I'm not aware of, this is invalid.

Comment: @Litty It is called a trailing return type.  It was added so we could use the template types to determine the return value.

Comment: Well you learn something new every day. Why isn't your first declaration allowed?

Comment: @Litty was just a mistake on my side. forgot to change it to the style of my example code. edited it

Comment: @Litty decltype needs a expression, not a conjunction of different datatypes (so i can't say decltype(double-int))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
template <typename T>
class XY{
private:
    T x;

template <typename U, typename S>
friend auto operator-(const XY<U> z1, const XY<S> z2)->XY<decltype(z1.x - z2.x)>;

};

template <typename T, typename S>
auto operator-(const XY<T> z1, const XY<S> z2)->XY<decltype(z1.x - z2.x)>{...}
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/WMNB24350)

Comment: Yes this is excactly what i'm looking for. I had this version very similar, but i used instead of template <typename U, typename S>: template <typename T, typename S> or just template <typename S>. Can you maybe explain me, why do i need another template parameter instead of my already existing T?

Comment: Because you want your `operator-` to be a function template with two template parameters, don't you?

Comment: yes, but my question was more about why do i need U and S instead of T and S. Why can't i use my T here?

Comment: If you try, you'll get an error. E.g. on clang: "declaration of 'T' shadows template parameter". There's a syntactical rule that say, essentially, that the name of a template parameter shouldn't be reused something else. Not sure why; I guess it makes the grammar ambiguous otherwise. It's a good advice to follow to avoid confusion, in any case.